# Simplyfing $(\lambda y. z)((\lambda x. x x)(\lambda x. x x))$

Tags: computer-science, computability, lambda-calculus

I need to simplify this expression.

$(\lambda y. z)((\lambda x. x x)(\lambda x. x x))$

However, what's interesting to me are two things:

1. Should I start simplifying $((\lambda x. x x)(\lambda x. x x))$ first because they fall under the same pair of brackets? This sort of reminds me of $2+(3+4)$ but of course we know that addition is associative
2. What do I do with $((\lambda x. x x)(\lambda x. x x))$? This is an irreducible form using alpha, beta and eta reductions.

What I tried doing is first simplifying $(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda x.xx)$, but I just get the same expression all over again. This is because this is irreducible using alpha, beta and eta rules. Right now, I am not sure if I should already call this simplified as much as possible, or is there something else I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The expression $(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda x.xx)$ can't be reduced any more. It is a famous example of a lambda expression that doesn't have a normal form.

In the untyped lambda calculus we can do beta reduction on any redex. By [Church-Rosser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Rosser_theorem) order of beta reductions is not important.

Therefore, it is better to do a beta reduction of outer redex $(\lambda y.z) M \rightarrow_\beta z$. Result is, of course, in a normal form.

But as you can see, you would get the same result even if you did $n$ reductions of inner redex and then do a reduction of outer redex. This is a demonstration of Church-Rosser theorem.

Comment: Since I'm new to this I'm not sure what redex means. 

Does it mean that I should first do $(\lambda y.z)(\lambda x. xx) $so it ends up being $(\lambda y.z)(\lambda y.z)$?

Comment: @l0ner9 You seem to be attempting to apply $\lambda x.xx$ to $\lambda y.z,$ but that's backwards: things on the left apply to things on the right. Furthermore, note $((\lambda x. xx)(\lambda x. xx))$ is grouped together, so you'd be applying $\lambda x.z$ to that entire expression, not to just one of them. The two choices for a beta reduction step here (outer redex, and inner redex, respectively) are to apply $\lambda y.z$ to $((\lambda x. xx)(\lambda x. xx))$ or to apply $(\lambda x. xx)$ to $(\lambda x. xx).$ The former reduces the expression to $z$ whereas the latter leaves it unchanged.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Sorry for the late reply, but I'm having problems understanding "applying" something to something else.

If I want to apply λy.z to ((λx.xx)(λx.xx)), am I "plugging in" λy.z to both instances of (λx.xx)? So I'd have 

((λy.z)(λy.z))((λy.z)(λy.z)).

Is this correct?

Comment: @l0ner9 "apply" as in apply a function. When you apply $\lambda y.z$ to anything you get $z,$ since $\lambda y.z$ is the constant function that always returns $z.$

Answer (score 1):

1. As answered by @Nikola Ubavić, the Church-Rosser theorem allows you to β-reduce the redexes in any order, so you should indeed reduce the outer redex if you want the reduction to terminate.
2. However,

   > — What do I do with $((λx.xx)(λx.xx))$? This is an irreducible form using alpha, beta and eta reductions.
   >
   > — You are right. The expression $(λx.xx)(λx.xx)$ can't be reduced any more.

let me stress that $(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda x.xx)$ is **not** irreducible: as you observed, it can be reduced — to itself. It's not just a matter of talking, there are actual (and valid) infinite reductions starting from your term, and what you look for is not “the” reduction but “a good” reduction strategy.

---

(SE didn't want me to post this as comment, so I wrote an answer...)